# In fish shell how to check if a variable is a number?

Tags: shell, fish

How to check if a variable is a number in fish shell?
Looking for a simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution is using `string match` as follows:

```
for arg in 9 -42 0 3.14159 stack overflow hyphenated-word 922-99999 0...0 555.555.555
    if string match -qr '^-?[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]*)?$' -- "$arg"
        echo $arg is a number
    end
end

9 is a number
-42 is a number
0 is a number
3.14159 is a number
```

If `num` is not a number nothing is echo-ed.

Here's `string match` synopsis from fish shell documentation (https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string):

```
string match [(-a | --all)] [((-e | --entire)] [(-i | --ignore-case)] [(-r | --regex)]
         [(-n | --index)] [(-q | --quiet)] [(-v | --invert)] PATTERN [STRING...]
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to do it. I needed only positive integers and this worked `string match -qr '^[0-9]+$' -- $SOME_VARIABLE`

Answer (score 2):

Check if there's a non-digit in the variable:

```
if not string match --quiet --regex '\D' $var; ...
# or
if string match --quiet --regex --invert '\D' $var; ...
```

Comment: Your first suggestion doesn't seem to work if `$var` is set to something like: `123asd`.

Comment: can you provide a string where it "doesn't work"? `set var 1234; if string match -qra '\d+' $var; echo $var is a number; end` -- Do you want to match floating point numbers?

Comment: I have edited my comment, I meant something like `123asd`.

Comment: I reread the docs, and `--all` is not what I was thinking of. I understand you were telling me that "123asd" was falsely reporting positively as a number. My apologies.

Comment: My confusion was "doesn't work" -- that's not a very informative error report.

Comment: I have to agree with that. I believe it's all sorted now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think fish is taking some inspiration from Tcl: the string subcommands are very similar: [fish](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string) vs [Tcl](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm).

One nice subcommand from Tcl is `string is` where you can say

```
if {[string is integer $num]} {
    puts "$num is an integer"
}
```

I've hacked up a function to expose `string is [class] [string]` in fish:

```
function string  --wraps=string
    if set -q argv[1]; and [ $argv[1] = "is" ]
        if not set -q argv[2]
            echo "error: usage..." >&2
            return
        end
        set -l pattern
        switch $argv[2]
            case int integer
                set pattern '^[+-]?\d+$'
            case hex hexadecimal xdigit
                set pattern '^[[:xdigit:]]+$'
            case oct octal
                set pattern '^[0-7]+$'
            case bin binary
                set pattern '^[01]+$'
            case float double
                set pattern '^[+-]?(?:\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$'
            case alpha
                set pattern '^[[:alpha:]]+$'
            case alnum
                set pattern '^[[:alnum:]]+$'
            case '*'
                echo "unknown class..." >&2
                return
        end
        set argv match --quiet --regex -- $pattern $argv[3]
    end
    builtin string $argv
end
```

Answer (score 2):

My attempt:

```bash
math "0+$argv[2]" 2>/dev/null
if test $status -ne 0
    echo "argv 2 is not numeric"
else
    echo "argv 2 was numeric"
end
```

Comment: I don't think you need to do 0+.

Comment: This is should be an accepted solution. What about "0+": you need 0+, so if you give an argument like "--help" it won't invoke a help message for the built-in math command in your script/function. Because `math "--help"` == `math --help`.

Answer (score 0):

The `test` function (implicitly) validates inputs. For example, if you do `test a -lt 3` ("less than"), it will output `false` and give an error because `a` is not a number. You can (ab)use this by finding a condition that returns true for all numbers, but errors for non-numbers:

```bash
function is_number -a input
    test $input -lt 0 -o $input -ge 0 2>/dev/null
end
```

This checks the condition `$input < 0 || $input >= 0`. Obviously, this returns `true` for all numbers. For non-numbers, this returns `false`. I added `2>/dev/null` to suppress error messages from being displayed.

**Caveat:** This also allows numbers surrounded by whitespace and hexadecimal numbers. You can convert those to decimal using `math $input`.

---

You can also modify this to allow only positive numbers:

```bash
function is_positive_number -a input
    test $input -gt 0 2>/dev/null
end

function is_nonnegative_number -a input
    test $input -ge 0 2>/dev/null
end
```